# Add mp3 files to an iOS app's internal storage from the files app

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, assets

I'm trying to build a music player app in Swift and I want to be able to add mp3 files to the app's internal storage.

Right now I have a bunch of music files in the assets folder and i can play those files. I want to be able to add new files to the app from outside the app into that assets folder, copying the mp3 files from somewhere else, like the Files app for example.

Is there some kind of way to copy an mp3 file and add it to the assets folder of the app? Maybe it could be done using UIPasteboard?

Comment: Remember you can not and you are not allowed to add or edit file to assets or assets folder after you lunched your app, only developer can add file or folder to assets folder and also before lunching app, so your idea writing on assets was and is completely WRONG, assets folder is Just read-Only not read-write, maybe it could be must important things to learn here that no more changing is possible after lunching app in assets folder! It is assets folder man, THE ASSETS!

Comment: thanks, i actually didn't know that

Comment: I know, that is why I said like this to remember it for ever and ever, repeat like this, and we do never mess with assets again: It is assets folder man, THE ASSETS!  for your information plist is also just read-only after lunch, so what we say? we say: It is plist man, THE PLIST!

Comment: thanks dude, i've got it :D can you recommend a book or a comprehensive course on iOS programming?

Comment: that was a good idea to stop building app and learning to the right way of building apps! I gave you 2 kind of source, as Website and as Video, both are 100% good and useable as Pro or Amateur, Just chose one section or topic and focus on that and do not jump back and front, For website: https://learnappmaking.com For Videos: https://www.youtube.com/c/StewartLynch both are Free source but you can donate them If you like to help them continue, I want gave last link for your Basic information: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: i'll check these out, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Why only Assets folder? you can use other folders to store your files, for example Documents (inside your app) and can create more folders inside. Look forward for FileManager class.

Comment: i'll look into FileManager and using Documents, thanks. i didn't know how else to save files in an app, that's why i used assets.
how could i copy files into the app? say i copy a file from somewhere else, how can i access that copy? using UIPasteboard or is there some other way?

Comment: it depends of sources of files. it can be Data in Pasteboard, so you have to create file and write this data to it, or it can be some temporary file if you implement file downloading from network, for example, in this case you have to copy it to place you need. Assets folder is only for resources you can add during application develop, not after app was run.